# AJAX success returns old result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm sendint serialized data to  items.php file with AJAX, I'm checking result with FireBug, AJAX send data like this `category=2` my items.php file is:

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');
if (isset ($_POST['category'])) {
$kat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
if ($kat == 0){
 $kat = '';
}elseif ($kat == 1){
 $kat = 'ORDER BY date DESC';
}elseif ($kat == 2) {
    $kat = 'ORDER BY price DESC';
}elseif ($kat == 3) {
    $kat = 'ORDER BY price';
}
}else{ $kat = '';}
        $query = "SELECT * FROM prekes ".$kat."";
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
        $q = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $i = 0;
        while($f = mysql_fetch_array($q)){

        echo '<div kaina="'.$f['kaina'].'" class="prekes"><img src="prekes/'.$f['foto'].'">'.$f['pavadinimas'].'<br /><strong>'.$f['kaina'].'Lt </strong></div>';
        }
        ?>
```

and here is my AJAX success function:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'items.php',
        data: cleaned,
        success: function () {          
                              $('#items').fadeOut("fast").load("items.php?ts="+ $.now()).fadeIn("fast");
    }
   });
```

Div refreshes after success, but I'm getting old, unordered result. Why does it happening?

Comment: You might not want to response with HTML. Try using `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `load` method uses jQuery `get` method internally, I guess you are getting **cached** data. Make sure to send a unique key as part of the querystring and it will give you the new content /result /uncached data. You may use the `Date` object to get create a new unique string;

```
$('#items').fadeOut("fast").load("items.php?ts="+new Date().getTime())
```

**EDIT :** jQuery has a small method called  [`$.now()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/) to give you a unique timestamp. you may use that instead of writing the Date().getTime() method.

```
$('#items').fadeOut("fast").load("items.php?ts="+ $.now())
```

> The $.now() method is a shorthand for the number returned by the
>   expression (new Date).getTime().

Thanks [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400654/kevin-b) for pointing out. :)

**EDIT 2** : After seeing the code

**1)** You are not passing the `category` querystring value which is being used to return the ordered list.You should pass that like this

```
$('#items').fadeOut("fast").load("items.php?category=2&ts="+ $.now())
```

**2)** `load` method is a `GET` request. in your PHP code(items.php) you are accessing it using $_POST(is that correct ? Shouldnt be [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) ?

So Change

```
$kat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
```

to

```
$kat = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']);
```

Comment: Also of note, jQuery provides a helper method for this. `"items.php?ts=" + $.now())`

Comment: @Shyju I' still getting old data. When checking in firebug, post method in response gets coorect data, but when I open get line (which is after post line) there is old unordered data.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks. Never knew abt it. I added it to the answer and mentioned you.

Comment: @OsvaldaKazlaučiūnaitė : Are you sure is it going to your success handler and calling the load method there ?

Comment: @OsvaldaKazlaučiūnaitė Are you passing the category querystring value to the items.php, if not it will not return the order list. rite ? and you are reading via $_POST which is for HttpPost. load method uses GET. See my updated answer

Comment: @Shyju I'm quite new on this AJAX stuff, could you explain a little bit more about `1) You are not passing the category querystring value which is being used to return the ordered list` that stuff? `var kat = $(this.form).serialize();
var cleaned= kat.replace(/[^&]+=\.?(?:&|$)/g, '');`

Answer (score 4):

To prevent any ajax calls from being cached I generally have a global function setup.

(This is function independent, ie post/get/etc)

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
         cache: false
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `.load('items.php')` which uses a GET requests and by design GET requests are cached in the browser so it does not have to keep looking up things. Set the proper headers on the server so the page is not being cached.

```
<?php
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 00:00:00 GMT"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add header no-cache

headers: {
                'Cache-Control':'no-cache'
            }